# Telegram Bot - how to get a group chat id?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've been using [telegram_bot](https://github.com/eljojo/telegram_bot), and trying to get groupChat id to send notifications to group chat, but don't know which methods I have to use for it.

For getting chat id I use to message.chat.id when the bot participated in the chat but which I have to use for getting group chat id can't find/

Comment: I manage a bot for this. I hope this will help, check this <http://stackoverflow.com/a/37396871/6223024>

Answer (score 611):

In order to get the group chat id, do as follows:

1. Add the Telegram BOT to the group.
2. Get the list of updates for your BOT:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/getUpdates
```

Ex:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:jbd78sadvbdy63d37gda37bd8/getUpdates
```

3. Look for the "chat" object:

```json
{
    "update_id": 8393,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 3,
        "from": {
            "id": 7474,
            "first_name": "AAA"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": <group_ID>,
            "title": "<Group name>"
        },
        "date": 25497,
        "new_chat_participant": {
            "id": 71, 
            "first_name": "NAME",
            "username": "YOUR_BOT_NAME"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample of the response when you add your BOT into a group.

4. Use the "id" of the "chat" object to send your messages.
5. (If you created the new group with the bot and you only get `{"ok":true,"result":[]}`, remove and add the bot again to the group)
6. Private chart only works in image `argoprojlabs/argocd-notifications:v1.1.0` or above.

Comment: can u provide an example?

Comment: How to add bot to group? Created a bot, Did /setjoingroups. What is the next step?

Comment: Jost got to your bot profile and click "add to group". Bots can't be invited into group like normal users.

Comment: @WannaBeCoder, you can add a BOT to a group just like any other member: Go to your group properties, click on add member, then use the search icon to look for the BOT's name. BUT, keep in mind that since recent changes on Telegrams groups, you must be a group "admin" to add a new member, whether they are BOTs or not.

Comment: @Maverick_Java I was not the group admin. Figured out now. Thanks.

Comment: For newly created group `getUpdates` request returns `{"ok":true,"result":[]}` even if I try to send bunch of messages to the group and mention bot via `@` and some random "commands" `/my_id`, `/start`, `/help`. Any ideas what to do? - UPDATE: OK, removing bot from group, and adding bot back fixed this issue (also it printed chat id in the group) --- looks like bot can't be added during group creation.

Comment: @rutsky glad you got it working. removing and adding to group 2nd time was not the resolution here ... cant get chat id and also for me getUpdates request returns {"ok":true,"result":[]}

Comment: this returns: {"ok":true,"result":[]}

Comment: Hi @Tom. Have you already tried rutsky solution: "removing bot from group, and adding bot back fixed this issue (also it printed chat id in the group) --- looks like bot can't be added during group creation. " ? I have faced the same problem a couple of times, and removing the bot from group and adding it over again always solved the problem. Let me know if this won't help you.

Comment: @Maverick_Java yep it worked. i just added a different bot (and made sure to make the changes prior to adding it)

Comment: @tom, if you get {"ok":true,"result":[]} , type something into the bot channel. After this, you should get chat_id

Comment: You can use url https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/getme

Comment: (If you created the new group with the bot and you only get {"ok":true,"result":[]}, remove and add the bot again to the group)

It save me, thank you

Comment: step 2: `{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}%`

Comment: after you created the bot, open bot and click Start then it will return chat_id

Comment: To clarify what @WasimA. said: You need to start a chat with the bot, like with a normal user, then press start. That issues a `/start` command. But - this still doesn't help. I still get `{"ok":true,"result":[]}`

Comment: If you got `{"ok":true,"result":[]}` - make the bot administrator

Comment: Just send a message to the bot other than /start and it will show

Answer (score 319):

Here is the sequence that worked for me after struggling for several hours:

Assume the bot name is **my_bot**.

**1- Add the bot to the group.** 
Go to the group, click on group name, click on Add members, in the searchbox search for your bot like this: @my_bot, select your bot and click add.

**2- Send a dummy message to the bot.** 
You can use this example: `/my_id @my_bot`
(I tried a few messages, not all the messages work. The example above works fine. Maybe the message should start with /)

**3- Go to following url:** `https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:YYYY/getUpdates`
replace XXX:YYYY with your bot token

**4- Look for "chat":{"id":-zzzzzzzzzz,**
-zzzzzzzzzz is your chat id (with the negative sign).

5- **Testing:** You can test sending a message to the group with a curl:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:YYYY/sendMessage" -d "chat_id=-zzzzzzzzzz&text=my sample text"
```

If you miss step 2, there would be no update for the group you are looking for. Also if there are multiple groups, you can look for the group name in the response ("title":"**group_name**").

Comment: Excellent breakup on how to get a BOT configured.

Comment: I sent *one* message to the bot but it didn't work instantly, waiting a few seconds (or probably minutes) and trying curl again worked.

Comment: I cant get my bot working in the group, I get {"ok":true,"result":[]} in the browser. Hope someone can help me out

Comment: This worked for me. One thing, if you have webhooks configured, you have to disable it. Thanks!

Comment: are we replacing the word bot with the actual name of the bot created ? Banging my head against a wall here trying to get the chat id of a group ive created, thanks

Comment: @TheMrkt It seems, as said apadana, that sendind a message starting with `/` like  `/test something` makes getUpdates happy.

Comment: @ TheMrkt, you follow "Hoi_A " answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291868/where-to-find-the-telegram-api-key. It's working for me...

Comment: -(negative) sign is very important. If it is negative then it is group else private.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me who's new to chatbot dev, but wouldn't this be a worthwhile addition to the documentation?

Comment: I just sent "Test" to my not and I found this message in updates. (Maybe for private chats different but I would think not, if not explicitly disabled)

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for me. I used my https://api.telegram.org/here contains my bot token/getUpdates, it doesn't work at all. It keeps saying "{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}"

Comment: Same as @CCCC I get `{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}%`

Comment: This solution works well ultil July, 2022 when no webhook setup in your group. If you had setup webhook already, just check logs in your webhook received data.

Comment: Make sure that your bot is not running in any computer. In that case, it will consume (not sure if this is the right word or not) update messages. Otherwise, you will see `{"ok":true,"result":[]}`

Answer (score 252):

As of May 2021, simply:

- Invite **@RawDataBot** to your group.

Upon joining it will output a JSON file where your **chat id** will be located at **message.chat.id**.

```
"message": {
    "chat": {
        "id": -210987654,
        "title": ...,
        "type": "group",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Be sure to kick @RawDataBot from your group afterwards.

Comment: Where should @RawDataBot output this? I added the bot to my group, but nothing happend.

Update: you need to have an username set in Telegram, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @Cherona: I just re-verified it. But it seems that the web client has changed such that inviting the bot is a bit harder than it used to be. Here's how you can do it: Search for RawDataBot in the search field. Click the contact to start a chat session. Click the chat title to open "Contact info". Click "Add to group" and choose the group. It will immediately output the info as before. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Working perfectly fine as of May 2021.

Comment: It's actually @raw_data_bot which did the job for me.

Comment: OR Invite @ShowJsonBot to your group.

Comment: It's actually @raw_data_bot which did the job for me.

Comment: warning: there are a few similar bots to get the channel id and some use it to get user ids and spam them afterward

Answer (score 89):

**After mid-2018:**
1:) Invite [@getidsbot](https://t.me/getidsbot) or `@RawDataBot` to your group and get your group id from the chat id field.

```
Message
 ├ message_id: 338
 ├ from
 ┊  ├ id: *****
 ┊  ├ is_bot: false
 ┊  ├ first_name: 사이드
 ┊  ├ username: ******
 ┊  └ language_code: en
 ├ chat
 ┊  ├ id: -1001118554477    // This is Your Group id
 ┊  ├ title: Test Group
 ┊  └ type: supergroup
 ├ date: 1544948900
 └ text: A
```

2:) use an unofficial Messenger like [Plus Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus) and see your group id in group/channel info.

**Before mid-2018:** (don't Use)
1: Goto (https://web.telegram.org)
2: Goto your Gorup and Find your link of Gorup(https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=g154513121)
3: Copy That number after g and put a (-) Before That `-154513121`
4: Send Your Message to Gorup
`bot.sendMessage(-154513121, "Hi")`
I Tested Now and Work like a Charm

Comment: Very simple. Thanks! Tested in Grafana Alert Notification. So far, so good.

Comment: @Sedric Heidarizarei what if this is a not a number as like this (https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@welcomeworld)

Comment: '@welcomeworld' is your channel username, you can forward a message to '@getidsbot' and get your id

Comment: did the same but encountered with error OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER ... client.send_message(-1240933195_1386556410045688xx08.'Hi')

Comment: I updated my answer, This method does not work anymore, Temporarily use the `After mid-2018` method.

Comment: Please note that `@getidsbot` can read all messages in the channel. They have not enabled the privacy settings for it.

Answer (score 68):

the simplest way i found ***using only telegram-web*** :

- open [web.telegram](https://web.telegram.org/) in browser ( chrome in my case )
- right click on the group name on the left menu
- click 'inspect' button
- you will see the group id in the attribute
  **data-peer-id="-xxxxxxxxxx" or peer="-xxxxxxxxxx"**

group chat id : **-xxxxxxxxxx**

channel chat id : **-100xxxxxxxxxx**

(for some channels/groups you need to **add -100 prefix**)

Edit :
in some cases the ID is shown **in the browsers address bar** when you click a group name

https://web.telegram.org/z/#-xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: But they started to catch right-button clicks, so may be useful to open web inspector and start `Choose an element` located in upper left corner

Comment: This didn't work for me, HTML does not store any data attributes.

Comment: yes it seems there is some update to hide the html attributes,
however you can still get the id in web-telegram ,
once you click the chat name the id apears on the addresse bar of the browser (chrome for me)


https://web.telegram.org/z/#-xxxxxxxx

Comment: THIS is the new way. I searched more than an hour for it and this is it. Thank you so much!
Also: Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 if you are unable to open Inspect Element through right click.

Comment: Now I can see the id using web.telegram, when click in channel the id is in the browser. https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=cXXXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.

Comment: prefixing the group from the url with the -100 did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

You can get Chat ID in this way.

On private chat with your bot, send a random message. You will search this message later.

Get Your API-token from bot_father : `XXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY_YY`

Then, on your browser make a request with that url :

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY_YY/getUpdates
```

The request returns a json response, in json text search your `random message` and get chat id in that object.

Answer (score 15):

Using python and telethon it's very easy to get chat id. This solution is best for those who work with telegram API.

If you don't have telethon, run this:

```
pip install telethon
```

If you don't have a registered app with telegram, register one: [image]
The link is this: https://my.telegram.org/

Then run the following code:

```
from telethon import InteractiveTelegramClient
from telethon.utils.tl_utils import get_display_name

client = InteractiveTelegramClient('session_id', 'YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER', api_id=1234YOURAPI_ID, api_hash='YOUR_API_HASH')

dialog_count = 10
dialogs, entities = client.get_dialogs(dialog_count)
for i, entity in enumerate(entities):
                    i += 1  # 1-based index
                    print('{}. {}. id: {}'.format(i, get_display_name(entity), entity.id))
```

You may want to send a message to your group so the group show up in top of the list.

Answer (score 14):

- go on the group of choice
- add @rose bot
- type the command /id
- type the command /id[image]

Answer (score 13):

My second Solution for the error {"ok":true,"result":[]}

1. Go in your Telegram Group
2. Add new User (Invite)
3. Search for "getidsbot" => `@getidsbot`
4. Message: `/start@getidsbot`
5. Now you see the ID. looks like 1068773197, which is -1001068773197 for bots (with -100 prefix)!!!
6. Kick the bot from the Group.
7. Now go to the Webbrowser an send this line (Test Message):

```
https://api.telegram.org/botAPITOKENNUMBER:APITOKENKEYHERE/sendmessage?chat_id=-100GROUPNUMBER&text=test
```

*Edit the API Token and the Group-ID!*

Comment: /start@getidsbot does not respond with anything

Comment: @MichaelA. invite the getidsbot bot and he give all infos

Answer (score 12):

You can retrieve the group ID the same way. It appears in the message body as `message.chat.id` and it's usually a negative number, where normal chats are positive.

Group IDs and Chat IDs can only be retrieved from a received message, there are no calls available to retrieve active groups etc. You have to remember the group ID when you receive the message and store it in cache or something similar.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm this is true? I'm close to saying yeah after reading through the documents. I'd like to be able to get the chat_id from the group link in order to fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 10):

Group chat id should start with **-** (minus) is essential

```
This is wrong
10540154212

This is correct
-10540154212
```

Comment: This is more of a comment, but an important one.

Answer (score 6):

create a bot, or if already created set as follows:

has access to messages

apparently, regardless of how old/new the Telegram group is:

1. add a bot to the group
2. remove bot from the group
3. add bot again to the group
4. create a script file and run `getUpdates` method
   example:

```js
    var vApiTokenTelegram = "1234567890:???>yg5GeL5PuItAOEhvdcPPELAOCCy3jBo"; // @?????Bot API token
    var vUrlTelegram = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + vApiTokenTelegram;

    function getUpdates() {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/getUpdates");
        console.log(response.getContentText());
    }
```

5. function shall log to the console the following:

```
[20-04-21 00:46:11:130 PDT] {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":81329501,
"message":{"message_id":975,"from":{"id":962548471,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Trajano","last_name":"Roberto","username":"TrajanoRoberto","language_code":"en"},"chat":{"id":-1001202656383,"title":"R\u00e1dioRN - A voz da na\u00e7\u00e3o!","type":"supergroup"},"date":1587454914,"left_chat_participant":{"id":1215098445,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"MediaFlamengoRawBot","username":"MediaFlamengoRawBot"},"left_chat_member":{"id":1215098445,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"MediaFlamengoRawBot","username":"MediaFlamengoRawBot"}}},{"update_id":81329502,
"message":{"message_id":976,"from":{"id":962548471,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Trajano","last_name":"Roberto","username":"TrajanoRoberto","language_code":"en"},"chat":{"id":-1001202656383,"title":"R\u00e1dioRN - A voz da na\u00e7\u00e3o!","type":"supergroup"},"date":1587454932,"new_chat_participant":{"id":1215098445,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"MediaFlamengoRawBot","username":"MediaFlamengoRawBot"},"new_chat_member":{"id":1215098445,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"MediaFlamengoRawBot","username":"MediaFlamengoRawBot"},"new_chat_members":[{"id":1215098445,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"MediaFlamengoRawBot","username":"MediaFlamengoRawBot"}]}}]}
```

6. Telegram group chat_id can be extracted from above message
   `"chat":{"id":-1001202656383,"title"`

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers unless each answer is truly distinct

Answer (score 5):

You can get your id by sending a `/start` message to the bot `userinfobot`

> Note: once u search for userinfobot in telegram u get many responses.
> Makesure u choose the one with `@bot` tag

Answer (score 4):

I tested now 4h but it dont work 2021 with the group-chat-id. All the time the error {"ok":true,"result":[]}

**But now i found a Solution:**

**1:)** install the "Plus Messenger" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus)

**2:)** go in the Group => Tap now on the "Group-Name" in the Head => Double Tap now on the Headline from the Group. A Info is comming: ID123456789 is copy in the clipboard

**3:)** go in the Group an paste the clipboard text. It´s you Groud-ID

**4:)** looks like 1068773197, which is -1001068773197 for bots (**with -100 prefix**)!!!

btw, you see the user-id too, on your profil.

**5:)** Now go to the Webbrowser an send this line (Test Message):

```
https://api.telegram.org/botAPITOKENNUMBER:APITOKENKEYHERE/sendmessage?chat_id=-100GROUPNUMBER&text=test
```

*Edit the API Token and the Group-ID*!

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best way to do this is using TeleThon, but given that [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44475489/4999991) by [apadana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3769451/apadana) is outdated beyond repair, I will write the working solution here:

```py
import os
import sys
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.utils import get_display_name

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

session_name = "<session_name>"
api_id = <api_id>
api_hash = "<api_hash>"
dialog_count = 10 # you may change this

if f"{session_name}.session" in os.listdir():
    os.remove(f"{session_name}.session")

client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    dialogs = await client.get_dialogs(dialog_count)
    for dialog in dialogs:
        print(get_display_name(dialog.entity), dialog.entity.id)

async with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

this snippet will give you the first `10` chats in your Telegram.

Assumptions:

- you have `telethon` and `nest_asyncio` installed
- you have `api_id` and `api_hash` from [my.telegram.org](https://my.telegram.org/)

Comment: This snippet does not work. I get `SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function`. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you couldn't use my answer. this is from a long time ago. I can't promise that I can fix it immediately.

Comment: I may have fixed it, but it requires a session file from some other bot. I post the code here in case anyone else stumbles upon the same problem. Seems to work as long as you have the session file:  https://gist.github.com/casper/444daf52c1fde5a1b839306b551f757f

Answer (score 1):

I successfully retrieved all my channel's and chat's IDs in Telegram using Python and the Telethon library. To use Telethon, you first need to install it via pip:

```bash
pip install telethon
```

After installing Telethon, utilize the following code snippet, which is adapted from the [Telethon Documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/quick-start.html), to retrieve all the chat IDs:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

# Replace 'YOUR_API_ID' and 'YOUR_API_HASH' with your actual Telegram API ID and hash
api_id = 'YOUR_API_ID'
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'

# Creating a Telegram client session
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # Iterating through all the dialogs (chats, groups, channels)
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        # Printing the name and ID of each dialog
        print(dialog.name, 'has ID', dialog.id)

# Running the client
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Save this script in a file, for example, `telegram_script.py`. Then, run the script in your command line or terminal with the following command:

```bash
python telegram_script.py
```

This script will list all your dialogs, including personal chats, group chats, and channels, with their respective names and IDs.

Be sure to replace `'YOUR_API_ID'` and `'YOUR_API_HASH'` with your actual Telegram API ID and hash, obtainable from [my.telegram.org](https://my.telegram.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the most obvious (and probably the simplest) answer isn't here.

As you are writing a bot, you can get the id with these three simple lines:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

Then just check the groupId from the console :D

And as you are probably trying to look the groupId to be able to send message to a group with your bot, the correct answer is probably this:

You don't use anymore the groupId. You use the group name (the one with https://t.me/careless_whisper) prefixed with @. And remember that your group **has to be public**. Source: [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)

So if your group name is careless_whisper the recipient will be @careless_whisper

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to note very specific case made me monkey around it.

I've got the `chat_id` with above steps in the format like `-1001379XXXXXX`. So I just supposed the real id is `1001379XXXXXX`, and left it in a such format to the grafana admin page. But in fact the id got this `-` as the integral part. If was really needed to be copied together with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function adminCheck( chat_id, name ) {
var bAdminCheck = false;
var contents = JSON.parse( getAdmin( chat_id ) );      
var i = 0;
while( !bAdminCheck && (i < contents.result.length ) ) {
    if( name == (contents.result[i].user.first_name + " " + contents.result[i].user.last_name) ) {
        bAdminCheck = true;  
    }
    i++;
}  
return bAdminCheck;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Indeed adding @RawDataBot
Give it 10 seconds to send you the message witch include the chat ID.

Comment: The bot at is `@raw_data_bot` for me

Answer (score -2):

If you are implementing your bot, keep stored a group name -> id table, and ask it with a command. Then you can also send per name.