# Where to find the Telegram Api Key

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-api

I am trying to find the Api Key for Telegram but I cannot find it. Where do I find it on the website? If I use the Api Id, I get the error `Incorrect Token Format` in the C# Console Application.

Comment: Attention! This question is not about Telegram bot. Find API key at  https://my.telegram.org

Answer (score 7):

Like ihoru mentioned in his answer, you can find all of your bots relevant information in BotFather.

So navigate to @BotFather in Telegram. If you have not yet created a bot do so by entering `/newbot`and follow the instructions on screen. You should get your key at the end of the process.

But now let's assume you already have a bot and can't find the key anymore. Again, go to @BotFather but this time enter `/mybots`. You should see something like this:

[image: Image of /mybots result in telegram]

Click/Touch whatever bot you would like your API key for, then you should see this:

[image: telegram botfather showing API key button]

Click the API Key button and tadaa there is your key:

[image: botfather displaying api key]

Answer (score 4):

You mean Telegram API for create a telegram application using C#, not  Telegram Bot API, right? to get API key. Please see the step by step below or for detail information you can see this [link](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id)

1. Sign up for Telegram using any application.
2. Log in to your Telegram core: https://my.telegram.org.
3. Go to ‘[API development tools](https://my.telegram.org/apps)’ and fill out the form.
4. You will get basic addresses as well as the api_id and api_hash parameters required 
   for user authorization.
5. For the moment each number can only have one api_id connected to it.

But if you need API for Telegram Bot, You can check the API your bot using BotFather.
for detail, you can check on this [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots)

I hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

In special official bot: https://telegram.me/BotFather

Additional information on official Telegram FAQ page:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#how-do-i-create-a-bot

Comment: It tells me the address wasn't understood when I open BotFather.

Comment: @SvenRonnlund you can try to find \@BotFather manually in Telegram

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for finding bot's token ? 
or are looking for telegram client api code ?

@BotFather , gives you the token of each bot you made.

for getting api token for making client , you must make developer account for telegram. it can be you personal account for telegram .