# telegram bot - Chat not found

Tags: telepot

I am totally new to telegram_bot. I want to execute a `bot.send_message()` in the following code (as commented in the code), but can't do so. Please help.

```
!pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
import telegram
bot = telegram.Bot(token='**************')
bot.send_message(chat_id='******', text="I'm sorry Dave I'm afraid I can't do that.")
```

It errors out as :

```
1 bot.send_message('mardepbot',"I'm sorry Dave I'm afraid I can't do that.")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py in decorator(self, *args, **kwargs)
     63     def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
     64         logger.debug('Entering: %s', func.__name__)
---> 65         result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     66         logger.debug(result)
     67         logger.debug('Exiting: %s', func.__name__)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telegram/bot.py in decorator(self, *args, **kwargs)
     88                 data['reply_markup'] = reply_markup
     89 
---> 90         result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=kwargs.get('timeout'))
     91 
     92         if result is True:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py in post(self, url, data, timeout)
    307             result = self._request_wrapper('POST', url,
    308                                            body=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
--> 309                                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    310 
    311         return self._parse(result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/telegram/utils/request.py in _request_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    221             raise Unauthorized(message)
    222         elif resp.status == 400:
--> 223             raise BadRequest(message)
    224         elif resp.status == 404:
    225             raise InvalidToken()

BadRequest: Chat not found
```

Comment: user that you want to send message to should start or do at least one action in your bot then you can send him any message.

Answer (score 8):

I just solved the similar issue. Please check:

1. Your bot settings Group Privacy must be OFF (Bot Father -> Group Privacy -> disable).
2. If your bot has been already added to chat, delete it, and re-add
3. Make sure, there is a '-' sign before your chat id, so if your chat link looks like: https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=g123456789, then your chat_id = '-123456789'

Comment: How to get the chat id?

Comment: This is discussed in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a message to a string ('mardepbot') as address. If mardepbot is the bot, you are using, then you made 2 errors; then you should use your own ID to send a message to yourself.