# How to get the list of all chat IDs in a given bot in Telegram?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am creating a telegram bot using a CRON job so it will update with every interesting movie/series release, and I want it to send an update once every month.

You can view it in this [GitHub Library](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots)

I have also seen other topics here in stackoverflow [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id).
But, this kind of solution does not apply to my problem, or I think so at least, since I do not have to have updates from every chat that my bot will be into since it will be a newsletter bot.

Basically I have:

```java
public void sendMessage(String message) {
        SendMessage messageSender = new SendMessage().setChatId(someId).setText(message);
        try {
            execute(messageSender);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Which is fine to send one message if you already know the chatId you want to send the message to. But, I would like to have a function (or a REST endpoint) that returns the list of chetIds my bot is attached to so that I can go for something like:

```java
List<Integer> chatIds = someMagicRESTendpointOrFunction();
chatIds.stream().forEach(message -> sendMessage(message));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not get all chatId's by Telegram API. See [official docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods).

I think best solution there is to store all chatId's in database or file.
You can get chatId from `update` variable from method `public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)` when user starts the bot or execute some actions:

```
long chatId = update.hasMessage() 
           ? update.getMessage().getChat().getId() 
           : update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChat().getId();
```

Example of file-based id store:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class FileUtil {

private static final String FILE_NAME = "chatIds.txt";

public static boolean writeChatId(long chatId) {
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);

        List<Long> adminChatIds = getChatIds();
        if (adminChatIds.contains(chatId)) return true;

        Files.write(path, (String.valueOf(chatId) + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static List<Long> getChatIds() {
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
        List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(path)) {
            result.add(Long.valueOf(line));
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

}
```