# Telegram bot sending message to itself but not in a public group

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot with @botfather and promoted the bot as admin of the public group. Whenever I try to send a message from the python code, it always sends the message to itself, I mean in the private chat and not in the public group.

Snapshot of the code written:

```
bot_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
bot_chatID = '395014927'
bot_message = "Testing"
send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&text=' + bot_message
response = requests.get(send_text)

response.json()
```

How can I make the bot to send the message in the group, not to itself?

Am I missing something here or do I need to modify some settings?

**EDIT(Solved) :** Chat group is always a negative number. Look for that number to get the chat id of that group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should send message to the group `chat_id`. It seems you are sending message to your bot itself or yourself. why? because `chat_id` of group or supergroup starts with `-` negative sign. for example : `-1001331798505` is `chat_id` of my **supergroup**.

```
  "ok": true,
  "result": [{
    "update_id": 751829615,
    "message": {
      "message_id": 5968,
      "from": {
        "id": 223110107,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "\u011e\u0105me",
        "last_name": "\u01fever!",
        "username": "GameO7er",
        "language_code": "en"
      },
      "chat": {
        "id": -257326110,
        "title": "This group is not Super Group",
        "type": "group",
        "all_member                                                                                                                           s_are_administrators": true
      },
```

as you can see **type:group**

and this is an example of **supergroup**

```
 {
   "ok": true,
   "result": [{
     "update_id": 751829616,
     "message": {
       "message_id": 141,
       "from": {
         "id": 223110107,
         "is_bot": false,
         "first_name": "\u011e\u0105me",
         "last_name": "\u01fever!",
         "username": "GameO7er",
         "language_code": "en"
       },
       "chat": {
         "id": -1001241538300,
         "title": "this groups is supergroup",
         "type": "supergroup"
       },
       "date": 1568644531,
       "text": "A"
     }
   }]
 }
```

as you can see **type:supergroup**

if you don't know how get ID of your groups you can read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id)

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with the chat id. It's working fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help ^_^