# How can a telegram bot broadcast a message to active chats / users

Tags: telegram-bot

We are building an internal bot to monitor / control our software. It is NOT exposed to the public and will be used by other team members, either directly (as a direct chat) or through a few channels depending which side of the software is on topic.

The bot should do two things:

- reply to commands; the reply should go to the user that originated it.
- send notices to all users / channels it is involved in.

When a message arrives, I can get the channel id and the user id; while the user id is kind of guaranteed to exist for while, what is the situation with the channel?

Can I store the channel id and broadcast messages to all channels the bot is involved in? what happens if a channel is closed? do channel ids have lifetimes?

I can't really find anything online about the best practice regarding this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have doubt Understand what you want but it seems better know these things :

- ID's are unique in Telegram and even in all others applications so
  they are lifetime
- Channel ID , Groups ID , User ID have same behavior but their difference is on their integer. (User ID's are Positive but channels and groups are Negative. [check example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949552/telegram-bot-sending-message-to-itself-but-not-in-a-public-group/57959173#57959173))
- Users can just send message in channels that they have `admin` permission in it right? Bots are same. so if your bot isn't admin anymore , the Telegram gives you error in response and you can check it and after facing that error delete that channel ID in your channels list.

I hope this information help you but if you have any other question feel free to leave a comment and I'll update the post and answer you immediately.

Comment: this answers the question; I was wondering if I can remember some groups and they still exist after some time

Comment: `Supergroups` and `groups` should exist permanently if the owner don't delete them. If owner of `supergroup` leave the group , the group will be delete automatically but it's not true about group. so you can always send message to `groups` and `supergroups` except when you restricted. In that situation Telegram response message will tell you about problem.