# Send a message on telegram: "Forbidden: bot is not a member of the supergroup chat" or "Forbidden: bot is not a member of the channel chat"

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to send a message on a chat on telegram.
I want telegram setups to be done only with the official UI as I want it to be possibly done by by an end user.

Here are telegram setup I do:

- I created the bot `XXXXXXX_bot` with Botfather by getting the token: no problem
- I created a Channel:

  - click "new channel"
  - channel name: `TestChannel`
  - click "Next"
  - select "Private channel"
  - click "Save"
  - Add my bot `XXXXXXX_bot`
  - Click "Make admin"
  - Click "Save"
- I create the chat:

  - open the channel `TestChannel`
  - on the channel menu, select "Manage Channel"
  - click on "Add a group" in the discussion
  - click on "Create a new group"
  - group name: `TestChannelChat`
  - click "Create"
  - click "Save"
- I add the bot to the new group:

  - open the group `TestChannelChat`
  - on the right panel, I click "add member"
  - Add my bot `XXXXXXX_bot`
  - click "Add"
  - right click on the newly added user in the chat and select "Promote to admin"
  - click "Save"

Here is the setup of admins of the channel:

[image]

At the end of the day, the setup of the chat/group is the following in the telegram UI:

[image]

I make the following http call :

```
GET https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXTOKENXXXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=@TestChannelChat&text=coucou
```

that gives me the following answer:

```json
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 403,
  "description": "Forbidden: bot is not a member of the supergroup chat"
}
```

I also made the following (to bypass the actual chat and directly publish a message in the channel):

```
GET https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXTOKENXXXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=@TestChannel&text=coucou
```

that gives me the following answer:

```json
{
  "ok": false,
  "error_code": 403,
  "description": "Forbidden: bot is not a member of the channel chat"
}
```

**One simple question, as a bot is also meant to broadcast messages, what part of its setup am I missing?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in a right track for working with Telegram bots. But first understand about `chat_id`.

`chat_id` is either chat **username** or **id** of the chat. You can set username only for Public chats/groups. In your case you have a private group and there's no username for it. The value for `chat_id` that you're passing `@TestChannelChat` doesn't belong to your chat. You have to pass the `id` of the chat or set a public username and pass it.

If you don't know how to check `id` of the chat, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38388851/10359385

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a neater way to get the id of the chat?

Comment: You can get from bot updates API too. https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates

Comment: This is what I did, but sending a dummy message to the chat, and then, polling received message by the bot is not very "neat". I expected something like api.telegram.org/MyUserTokenThatIGetIDontKnowHow/getChannels

Answer (score -1):

used send post/message your private chat:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(chat_type=[ChatType.SUPERGROUP])
async def send_chat_msg(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(f'Message in your private chat ', reply_markup=markup)
```