# How to send notification to Telegram from GitLab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, notifications, gitlab-ci, telegram

In our small startup we use GitLab for development and Telegram for internal communication between developers and PO. Since the PO would like to see the progress immediately, we have set up the GitLab Pipeline so that the preview version is deployed on the web server after each commit. Now we want to expand the pipeline. So that after the deployment a notification is sent via the Telegram group.

So the question - is that possible, and if so, how?

EDIT: since I've already implemented that, that's not a real question. I wanted to post the answer here so that others can use it as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, we'll go through it step by step:

1. Create a Telegram bot
2. Add bot to Telegram group
3. Find out Telegram group Id
4. Send message via GitLab Pipeline

## 1. Create a Telegram bot

There are enough good instruction from Telegram itself for this:

https://core.telegram.org/bots#6-botfather

The instructions do not say anything explicitly, but to generate it, you have to go into the chat with the BotFather.
At the end you get a bot token, something like `110201543:AAHdqTcvCH1vGWJxfSeofSAs0K5PALDsaw`

## 2. Add bot to Telegram group

Switch to the Telegram group, and add the created bot as a member (look for the bot by name).

## 3. Find out Telegram group Id

Get the update status for the bot in browser:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/getUpdates`

Find the chat-id in the response:
`... "chat": {"id": <YourGroupID>, ...`

see for more details: [Telegram Bot - how to get a group chat id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id)

## 4. Send message via GitLab Pipeline

Send message with a curl command. For example, an existing stage in gitlab pipeline can be extended for this purpose:

```
upload:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - 'apk --no-cache add curl'
    - 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"chat_id\": \"<YourGroupID>\", \"text\": \"CI: new version was uploaded, see: https://preview.startup.com\"}" https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/sendMessage '
  only:
    - main
```

Remember to adapt the `YourBOTToken` and `YourGroupID`, and the text for the message.

*) we use the alpine docker image here, so curl has to be installed `- 'apk --no-cache add curl'`. With other images this may have to be done in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to send notifications (particularly if you're using multiple services or chats) is to use [apprise](https://github.com/caronc/apprise/wiki/CLI_Usage).

To send to one telegram channel:

```sh
apprise -vv --body="Notify telegram chat" \
  tgram://bottoken/ChatID1 \
```

This makes it easy to notify many services from your pipeline all at once without needing to write code against the API of each service (apprise handles this for you).

```yaml
image: python:3.9-slim # or :3.9-alpine if you prefer a smaller image
before_script:
  - pip install apprise # consider caching PIP_CACHE_DIR for performance
script: | 
  # Set a notification to multiple telegram chats, a yahoo email account, 
  # Slack, and a Kodi Server with a bit of added verbosity:
  apprise -vv --body="Notify more than one service" \
    tgram://bottoken/ChatID1/ChatID2/ChatIDN \
    mailto://user:password@yahoo.com \
    slack://token_a/token_b/token_c \
    kodi://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that allows you to get notifications from Gitlab/Github/Bitbucket repos: [https://t.me/my_repobot](https://t.me/my_repobot?start=stackoverflow_referral)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34568289)