# Can't send message from my bot to myself -- chat not found

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I have created Telegram bot from `BotFather` and it gave me an API key. Now when I am trying to open this URL

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MYAPIKEY>/sendMessage?chat_id=@<MYTELEGRAMUSERNAME>&text=Hello
```

it responds me

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 400,
    "description": "Bad Request: chat not found"
}
```

How to fix? What I forgot to do?

I was trying to open my bot's page in telegram and type there something (it didn't respond anything).

---

I want my computer to send Telegram notifications to me.

Comment: The `@<username>` syntax works only for groups and channels, not user chats.

Comment: And? How to send to user then?

Comment: With their ID. :)

Comment: Where to get it?

Comment: It will be included in the [`User`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object in the updates your bot [gets](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates).

Comment: Answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id