# How to get a user's id from mentioning (@User)

Tags: telegram-bot

For example, if the user sends the bot `/text @USER` how do I get @USER's id and message them?

Question different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user) since the answer to that question requires said user (@USER) to already message the bot/the owner to already know the user's id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain Telegram chat\_id for a specific user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)

Comment: Not duplicate since the answer for "[How to obtain Telegram chat_id for a specific user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)" requires said user to already message the bot/the owner to already know the user's id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 conditions:

> 1-`@user` is not subscribed to your bot before(not initiated chat with your bot before or it does block your bot after some chat with your bot: In this condition you can NEVER send any type of message to that `@user`.
>
> 2-`@user` doesn't exist or is incorrect . As you know, a telegram user subscribe with phone and first name (at least) and he/she could not have any `@user` id: In this condition there is no user name to send.
>
> 3-`@user` exists and already is your bot subscriber. In this condition you should save all subscribers `chat_id` and their related `user_name` as they sends some messages to your bot in a database because these data are part of each message you receive from users. So for send to that `@user` you should find related `chat_id` from your DB.(Non of `Telegram Bot API` methods use `@username` but they use `chat_id`)

This is a sample JSON response from Telegram when user send `/1` command, as you see telegram always attaches sender `chat_id`,`firs_name`,`last_name` and `username`(if exists) to each message that bot receives:

[image: This is a sample JSON response from Telegram when user send <code>/1</code> command]

> **UPDATED**:
>
> As users may change they `@username` during the time, it is better to
>   update your `chat_id`<-->`@username` database with each message you
>   receive.

Comment: Using this and the `pickle` library I managed to store a users dictionary `{'@USER': 999999999}` as a file and load it whenever the bot starts up (if a new user sends it /start it'll add them to the dictionary)

Comment: I'll try to implement that. Do you know any way to update a dictionary in such a way that the key changes but the value does not?

Comment: @NoamBarnea ,I recommend you to use databases like MySQL and so on instead of handling a file .