# Telegram how to send message user from group through Api?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

On some website (http://ad1.ru/) I had seen possible get personal notify eq :(offer, ticket, discound) on telegram. I can to add only mobile phone (+7 906 247 00 01) in my contact list telegram and all.
**How they did it?**

I read  telegram api documention  and I found nothing. also I found this question [How to obtain Telegram chat_id for a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)

wherein said that before send message I can get chat_id and send message boot telegram for get user chat_id from message

Comment: I couldn't understand what do you want exactly to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After obtaining user's phone number you can send an SMS to that number with a link to a bot like https://telegram.me/YourBot?start={SOME_ID_ASSOICATED_WITH_PHONE_NUMBER}

Once user opens the link and start bot you can send him/here messages through bot until blocked/unsubscribed.

If a user with the same phone number already subscribed to the bot no need to send an SMS.

Comment: Thanks, Are there other ways ? if the user added my phone or bot name  he added in his contact list, how can I get his chat_id? Or it is not possible?

Comment: When user starts conversation with your bot or sends a message to it you get the chat_id. There are no other ways to get it as far as I know.