# How can I send a message to someone with my telegram bot using their Username

Tags: visual-studio-code, python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using the telepot python library, I know that you can send a message when you have someone's UserID(Which is a number).
I wanna know if it is possible to send a message to someone without having their UserID but only with their username(The one which starts with '@'), Also if there is a way to convert a username to a UserID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain Telegram chat\_id for a specific user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - this question is formulated more generally, to find the other question you have to know that you need a "chat_id" in the first place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't send message to users using their username that is in form of `@username`, you can just send messages to channel usernames which your bot is administrator of it. Telegram bot api uses `chat_id` identifier for sending messages. If you want to achieve `chat_id` of users, you can use [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/), but it's not easy at all because that project is discontinued and you should debug it yourself.
in your case you should do following command:

```
> resolve_username vahid_mas
```

and the output will be something like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "Vahid_Mas",
    "id": "$010000006459670b02c0c7fd66d44708",
    "last_name": "",
    "peer_type": "user",
    "print_name": "Vahid",
    "flags": 720897,
    "peer_id": 191322468,
    "first_name": "Vahid",
    "phone": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "online": false,
  "event": "online-status",
  "state": -1,
  "when": "2017-01-22 17:43:16"
}
```

Comment: Yo, as of 2022 is there any other methods? I couldnt get this to work.

Answer (score 93):

1. Post one message from User to the Bot.
2. Open `https://api.telegram.org/bot<Bot_token>/getUpdates` page.
3. Find this message and navigate to the result->message->chat->id key.
4. Use this ID as the [chat_id] parameter to send personal messages to the User.

Comment: Note: the first message NEEDS to be sent via phone not desktop :( 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880243/new-telegram-bot-return-almost-empty-json-to-api

Comment: The privacy of the bot much be changed to disabled so it works with desktop messages.

Answer (score 21):

It is only possible to send messages to users whom have already used /start on your bot. When they start your bot, you can find update.message.from.user_id straight from the message they sent /start with, and you can find update.message.from.username using the same method.
In order to send a message to "@Username", you will need them to start your bot, and then store the username with the user_id. Then, you can input the username to find the correct user_id each time you want to send them a message.

Answer (score 9):

As the user you want to learn the ID of, send a message of any content to `@JsonDumpBot`. It will reply the whole JSON element that it receives from Telegram, including the ID of the user:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try telethon:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

def send_msg(name, msg):
    with TelegramClient(session_file, app_id, app_hash, proxy=my_proxy) as client:
        # client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message('me', 'hello')) # send 'hello' to saved messages
        client.loop.run_until_complete(client.send_message(name, msg))
```

"name" can be "@xxxxx".

Then you can call send_msg(name, msg) in your bot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's totally not safe to use other telegram versions available on internet, but I've seen that [Telegram Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus&hl=en_US&gl=US) has a ability to show you the chat_id of the user in their profile, even tho you don't have their contact.

Another way to extract chat_id of that particular user is that you have the phone number of that account, save it as your contact, then share it to [this](https://telegram.me/get_id_bot) bot. It's easy to code it yourself but you can forward something from that user to this bot too, if you want to recieve the chat_id.

urmurmur has also mentioned another way. I haven't checked it yet but seems to be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

you can send bulk messages to people in telegram using by [v-user telegram bulk message sender](https://www.v-user.com/en/side-products/telegram-bulk-message-sender)