# New Telegram bot return almost empty JSON to API

Tags: json, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a Telegram bot, so I followed the instructions and got:

> Done! Congratulations on your new bot. You will find it at
>   t.me/RonGuruBot. You can now add a description, about section and
>   profile picture for your bot, see /help for a list of commands. By the
>   way, when you've finished creating your cool bot, ping our Bot Support
>   if you want a better username for it. Just make sure the bot is fully
>   operational before you do this.
>
> Use this token to access the HTTP API:
>   318659684:AAFdR9YE4DEwg1NQitSIuifPotoA-3f6cUw

However, when I enter the following URL into Chrome:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot318659684:AAFdR9YE4DEwg1NQitSIuifPotoA-3f6cUw/getUpdate`s

The returned JSON is:

> {"ok":true,"result":[]}

And the documentation led me to believe that there should be more in the JSON reply.

- Should there be more?
- What should I change to get a correct JSON reply?

Comment: You should probably regenerate that token now, as that's used to control your bot and you just posted it online to hundreds of people :P

Comment: I'm just 'feeling the waters', so don't really care. I'm aware of the `/token` command. Thanks for the heads-up, @Hoi_A. Any insights into my actual questions?

Comment: David's answer should be enough tbh. Your resulted JSON is completely fine and to be expected as there can't be an Updates object for you to receive if nothing has happened yet. Also since "ok" is true that means the request was correct as per the [API Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests)

Answer (score 10):

if you do not change the privacy settings,

the bot only receives messages beginning with `/` e.g. `/start`,

this can be painful research, especially in multi-user chats

a good strategy is to mention the bot in the group

(e.g. `/start @mybot_bot` )

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is about initiating first updates to the bot via Desktop app. When I sent a message to bot from my mobile app, I started to receive updates.

Answer (score 3):

every thing is fine. your bot didn't receive any updates. i sent a message to your bot and if you fetch the updates again you can see that.

Answer (score 3):

Albeit from 2017, this still pops up as one of the first results in Google and it is still relevant so ... in my case :

1. Send a message to the just created bot (like *hello*) just after the /start command
2. execute getUpdates again

Answer (score 1):

Is it running on telegram server or somewhere else?
I had the same issue. When I removed script from own server it started to give updates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with that. It seems that the parameter `offset` that is mentioned as optional in the doc, is not so and response will be empty without specifying that. I could solve the problem by setting `offset=0`.

Answer (score 0):

check bot settings about Webhook `https://api.telegram.org/bot<your_token>/getWebhookInfo` , because `getUpdates` method will not work if an outgoing webhook is set up (see [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo)).

if you have an error similar like this:

> raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
>   urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=50)

you should add parameter `timeout` to `getUpdates` method (see [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) about it)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple test bot and in the "Start" command I have put the following:

```
def start(update, context):
    print("CHAT ID: "+str(update.message.chat_id))
```

You execute the .py and then send /start command by telegram APP