# C# Send message to channel telegram from bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

i using some code to make channelpost "Hello Word"

```
string urlString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage?chat_id={1}&text={2}";
                string apiToken = "1143035780:AAEG5vU5j2_Nc5rLK8B2ORp3ItpYoNicokU";
                string chatId = "@kekcheburekks";
                string text = "Hello world!";
                urlString = String.Format(urlString, apiToken, chatId, text);
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlString);
                Stream rs = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rs);
                string line = "";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null)
                        sb.Append(line);
                }
                string response = sb.ToString();
```

But i am get exception - chatId not found!

Comment: Is that your actual token?

Comment: Please add a proper snippet of the exception you get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send a message to someone with my telegram bot using their Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664810/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-someone-with-my-telegram-bot-using-their-username)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you pass `@` symbol, try without it, like this:

```
string chatId = "kekcheburekks";
```

**Without using `@`** like this:

```
string chatId = "@kekcheburekks";
```