# Telegram bot: ChatId ? Not getting ChatId but {"ok":true,"result":[]}

Tags: telegram-bot

tried all the options as described in [Telegram bot - how to get a group chat id ? Ruby gem Telegram_bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423837/telegram-bot-how-to-get-a-group-chat-id-ruby-gem-telegram-bot).

When browsing to : https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:YYYY/getUpdates, all I get is:

{"ok":true,"result":[]}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

[How to obtain Telegram chat_id for a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)

"I created a bot to get User or GroupChat id, just send the /my_id to telegram bot @get_id.

It does not only work for user chat ID, but also for group chat ID.

To get group chat ID, first you have to add the bot to the group, then send /my_id in the group."

Answer (score 3):

try to send some massages to the new group.so there is some results to show. that worked for me