# want to save chat id inside database(telegram bot)

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

total newbie in telegram bot. i want to make a telegram bot that can save chat id inside the database and send notification to them. How can i implement it. im using node.js to make the bot btw

Comment: What did you done so far?

Comment: my bot can send location to user and redirect them to google map. i want to give them notification. but chat id need to be store first

Comment: I think you're problem by storing values in the database. it's true ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain Telegram chat\_id for a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)